# Setting background overlay but allowing text elements to sit on top

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an overlay blur over the background image for my container, which I've mostly done successfully but my main issue is the fact that I have  heading and a card which will have blocks of text and I want them to sit on the top of the stack but even modifying z-index hasn't seemed to do the trick.

How can I keep the blur effect while letting the title and card divs sit on top properly?

```css
.comfortBackground{
    background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547937414-009abc449011?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80');
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.comfortBlur{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
    background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547937414-009abc449011?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  filter:blur(10px);
  transition:filter .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.comfortCardContainer{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  right:25%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 ">
        <div class="comfortBackground">
            <div class="bannerTitle">
            <h1>Title</h1>
          </div>
      <div class="comfortCardContainer">
                Card Text
            </div>
            <div class="comfortBlur">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
.comfortCardContainer {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  right: 25%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

to this

```
.comfortCardContainer {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 25%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

all you needed to do was change the position to absolute, add a z-index of 1.